# Handwriting input, mainly done in Flash, curious how it recognizes characters

Tags: flash, ocr, cjk

http://www.nciku.com/ is a site that helps users look up Chinese Characters they don't know by writing into a flash app and then it searches a database bringing back relevant characters.

How does this work. It cannot be OCR because that would take forever. From the playing around I have done, stroke order does not really matter so I'm guessing it's more about shapes.

How is this done programmatically?

Comment: Stroke order does or does not matter?

Comment: That is a hard question. It does, but not really. Even if you have no idea how characters are supposed to be written, ie stroke order, you could still pretty much find anything you need.

Comment: Don't think about stroke order. I have and it's not really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that it is using stroke order for a first pass. On a second pass it would look at end points, edges, separation of radicals etc combined into some kind of visual comparison. Why do you need to know ?

Comment: If you want to write your own and you don't have any experience in pattern recognition then you'd better start with online handwriting recognition (i.e. using stroke order) because it's much easier.

Comment: This is a very good comment. I think I will start with stroke order, figure out how to do that, and then once I get that, FANN or SVM classes/neurons will be easier to implement. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a neural network.